# Matching values from two dictionaries or lists

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two separate CSV files:

One contains Company Name and the URL with that company and the other contains the Company URL with the phone numbers of that company from the URL.

Example for csv_1:

```
Company Name, Company_URL
comp_1 , comp_1_url
comp_2, comp_2_url
comp_3, comp_3_url
```

Example for csv_2:

```
Company URL, Company_Num
comp_1_url, comp_1_phone num 1
comp_1_url, comp_1_phone num 2
comp_2_url, comp_2_phone num 1
comp_3_url, comp_3_phone num 1
```

I want to associate the company name from the csv_1 to the results of csv_2.

expected outputs:

```
Company Name, Company URL, Company_Num
comp_1, comp_1_url, comp_1_phone num 1
comp_1, comp_1_url, comp_1_phone num 2
comp_2, comp_2_url, comp_2_phone num 1
comp_3, comp_3_url, comp_3_phone num 1
```

I have tried converting the CSV_1 to a dictionary, then matching the values (Company_URL) from the dictionary to urls (Company URL from CSV_2) from CSV_2 but need to find out how to get the phone numbers:

```
dictionary = {}
def dictionary_test():
    for key in companies:
        for value in companies_url_list:
            dictionary[key] = value
            # companies_url_list.remove(value)
            break

dictionary_test()

dictionary output:
{'comp_1':comp_1_url,'comp_2':comp_2_url,'comp_3':comp_3_url}

matches = [k for k, v in dictionary.items() if v in urls]
print(len(phone_numbers))
print(len(matches))
```

I need a way to append a list of the company name if the Company_url from CSV_1 matches the URL from CSV_2. What would be the best method to do this?

EDIT:

```
test_dict = {} #company_url from CSV_1 as key and comp_name as value
for key in comp_url:
    for value in comp_name:
        test_dict[key] = value
        break
```

Lists from CSV_2:

```
bbb_url = company_url_and_phone['URL Searched'].to_list()
bbb_phone = company_url_and_phone['Phone Numbers'].to_list()
```

Comment: Load them into pandas dataframes and join the dataframes.

Comment: They don't have the same length. Each company URL may return multiple results for phone numbers and the URL is appended to the list with the phone number.

Comment: Join doesn't require them to have the same length.

Comment: it will create multiple rows in the result for all the matching URLs.

Comment: Could you provide an short example answer below?

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary for csv_1 should use the URLs as the key. Then you don't need a loop. You can simply look up the company name using the URL from `csv_2`.

```
import csv

company_dict = {}
with open("csv_1.csv") as f:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in dr:
        company_dict[row['Company_URL'].strip()] = row['Company Name'].strip()

print("Company Name, Company URL, Company_Num")
with open("csv_2.csv") as f:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in dr:
        print(f"{company_dict[row['Company URL'].strip()]}, {row['Company URL'].strip()}, {row['Company_Num']}")
```

Comment: Im not following, i will edit my post to give you more information. I tried your code but it didnt work.

Comment: I had a typo, `dictReader` should be `DictReader`

Comment: I got rid of the spaces between fields in the CSV files in my test, and it worked.

Comment: I got it via merging in pandas. Thank you for your help